# Not returning mongo DB collection with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to simply display the collection I have on one of my databases, the course I am watching is a bit outdated on this subject in specific and I can't get it to work. If anyone can help, thank you. I'm using mongoose and nodejs

This is what I keep getting or something similar

```
<ref *2> Collection {
  collection: null,
  Promise: [Function: Promise],
  modelName: 'Person',
  _closed: false,
  opts: {
    autoIndex: true,
    autoCreate: true,
    schemaUserProvidedOptions: {},
    capped: false,
    Promise: undefined,
    '$wasForceClosed': undefined
  },
  name: 'people',
  collectionName: 'people',
  conn: NativeConnection {
    base: <ref *1> Mongoose {
      connections: [Array],
      nextConnectionId: 1,
      models: [Object],
      events: [EventEmitter],
      __driver: [Object],
      options: [Object],
      _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
      Schema: [Function],
      model: [Function (anonymous)],
      plugins: [Array],
      default: [Circular *1],
      mongoose: [Circular *1],
      cast: [Function: cast],
      STATES: [Object: null prototype],
      setDriver: [Function: setDriver],
      set: [Function (anonymous)],
      get: [Function (anonymous)],
      createConnection: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [AsyncFunction: connect],
      disconnect: [AsyncFunction: disconnect],
      startSession: [Function (anonymous)],
      pluralize: [Function (anonymous)],
      deleteModel: [Function (anonymous)],
      modelNames: [Function (anonymous)],
      plugin: [Function (anonymous)],
      version: '7.0.0',
      Mongoose: [Function: Mongoose],
      SchemaType: [Function],
      SchemaTypes: [Object],
      VirtualType: [Function: VirtualType],
      Types: [Object],
      Query: [Function],
      Model: Model { undefined },
      Document: [Function],
      ObjectId: [Function],
      isValidObjectId: [Function (anonymous)],
      isObjectIdOrHexString: [Function (anonymous)],
      syncIndexes: [Function (anonymous)],
      Decimal128: [Function],
      Mixed: [Function],
      Date: [Function],
      Number: [Function],
      Error: [Function],
      now: [Function: now],
      CastError: [class CastError extends MongooseError],
      SchemaTypeOptions: [class SchemaTypeOptions],
      mongo: [Object],
      mquery: [Function],
      sanitizeFilter: [Function: sanitizeFilter],
      trusted: [Function: trusted],
      skipMiddlewareFunction: [Function: skipWrappedFunction],
      overwriteMiddlewareResult: [Function: overwriteResult]
    },
    collections: { people: [Circular *2] },
    models: { Person: Model { Person } },
    config: {},
    replica: false,
    options: null,
    otherDbs: [],
    relatedDbs: {},
    states: [Object: null prototype] {
      '0': 'disconnected',
      '1': 'connected',
      '2': 'connecting',
      '3': 'disconnecting',
      '99': 'uninitialized',
      disconnected: 0,
      connected: 1,
      connecting: 2,
      disconnecting: 3,
      uninitialized: 99
    },
    _readyState: 2,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: false,
    plugins: [],
    id: 0,
    _queue: [ [Object] ],
    _listening: false,
    _connectionOptions: { driverInfo: [Object] },
    _connectionString: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/FruitDB',
    client: MongoClient {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0,
      mongoLogger: [MongoLogger],
      s: [Object],
      topology: [Topology],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    '$initialConnection': Promise { <pending> }
  },
  queue: [],
  buffer: true,
  emitter: EventEmitter {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

This is my code, I used .find() and showed a similar result but never details about the collection, just its name.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main();
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/People');
};

//Person Schema
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'You need a name']
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'You need to give me an age']
  }
});

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

personData();
async function personData(){
  const person = new Person({
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 32
  });
  //person.save();
};

console.log(Person.collection);
//i have tried Person.find() also doesn't work
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That output looks like a collection object, what were you expecting?

Comment: I want it to output the values in my collection like the name and age, Name: jerry and age:32